# Recursively iterate through all subdirectories, If a file with a specific extension exists then run a command in that folder once

Tags: shell-script, shell, find, recursive

I need to recursively iterate through all the subdirectories of a folder.
Within the subdirectories, if there's a file with an extension '.xyz' then I need to run a specific command in that folder once.

Here's what I have so far

```
recursive() {
  for d in *; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
      (cd -- "$d" && recursive)
    fi
  dir=`pwd`   
  pattern="*.xyz"
file_count=$(find $dir -name $pattern | wc -l)
if [[ $file_count -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "Match found. Going to execute a command"
    #execute command
fi
  done
}

(cd /target; recursive)
```

But the problem is that the "Match found.." message is displayed more than once per folder when there's a match. Is there a simpler way to do this while fixing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` has a builtin flag to print strings, which is pretty useful here:

`find -iname "*.xyz" -printf "%h\n"` prints the names of all directories that contain a file that matches your pattern (the `%h` is just `find`'s magic syntax that expands to the file directory  and `\n` is, of course, a linebreak).

Therefore, this does what you want:

```
COMMAND='echo'
find `pwd` -iname "*.pdf" -printf "%h\n" | sort -u | while read i; do                                              
    cd "$i" && pwd && $COMMAND
done
```

There are a few things that are going on here. To execute commands only once, we just pipe it through `sort` with the `-u` flag, which drops all duplicate entries. Then we loop over everything with `while`. Also note that I used `` find `pwd` ``, which is a nice trick to make `find` output absolute paths, instead of relative ones, which allows us to use `cd` without having to worry about any relative paths.

Edit: Be careful with your directory names when executing this script, as directory names containing a newline (`\n`) or even just `\` can break the script (maybe other uncommon characters too, but I haven't tested any more than that). Fixing this is hard and I don't know how to do it, so I can only suggest not using such directories.

Comment: Is `sort` really doing anything here? If it is, you could pass `-u` to sort to avoid `uniq`.

Comment: @MikaelKjær `sort` is needed because `find` can output directory `a`, then `a/b`, then `a` again. You're right about the `-u` flag, thanks! I'm too used to `sort|uniq`...

Comment: that `while read` loop splits words on whitespace, and will break if the pathname contains, e.g., spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.  The best you can do with a shell `while read` loop is to split on newline only (e.g. `... | IFS= while read -d '' i; do ... ; done`.  Then it will only break if the path/filename contains newline(s) - uncommon but valid.  Also, piping into a while loop prevents the loop from changing the parent scripts environment (because the pipe is executed in a subshell) - use process substitution instead if you need to do that.

Comment: @cas Really? The POSIX manual for `read` says that it reads a single line from stdin. I tested it with directories containing whitespaces on both bash and zsh, and it seems to work fine. You're right about the newlines of course. Your remark made me realize that it breaks with a name containing `\` too, which is still uncommon but not quite as eccentric as newlines.

Comment: `Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields`...but you're right about it assigning everything to your $i, it also says `with any leftover words assigned to the last NAME`...if there's only one var, then the first variable name is also the last variable name.    **However**, if the input line has 2+ spaces or a tab followed by a space or similar then (after splitting), `$i` will have only a single space instead of what was originally in the input.  There are many things that will break a `while read` loop.   BTW, newlines in filenames are quite common on, e.g., Macs.

Comment: The standard way to avoid such problems is to use NUL (i.e. `0x00` or `\000`) characters to separate the pathnames - NUL is the **ONLY** character that can not be in a full pathname (also, NUL and `/` are the **only** two characters that can not be in a filename or directory name).   That's why my answers either avoided problematic word-splitting by using NUL as separator, or avoided the problem entirely by doing everything inside `find -exec` (and carefully double-quoted all variables inside the shell scripts).

Comment: Unfortunately, shell scripts don't handle NUL characters well.  shell variables can not hold that value, so working with them directly in sh or bash is a bit of a pain.  Other tools, like find or xargs, or scripting languages like sed, awk, perl etc have no such problem.   The `IFS= while read -d '' i` I suggested is the standard/recommend way of splitting on newlines only (avoiding word split issues caused by other white-space characters) - this would not mangle consecutive spaces/tabs/etc.  Would still fail on filenames with embedded newlines.

Answer (score 6):

You're re-inventing `find`.

Try something like this (using GNU `findutils` and GNU `sort`):

```
find /target -iname '*.xyz' -printf '%h\000' | sort -z -u | 
  xargs -0 -r -I {} sh -c "cd {} ; yourcommandhere"
```

The `-printf` prints the directory names (`%h`) where '*.xyz' files are found, with NUL bytes (`\000`) as the delimiter.  `sort` is used to eliminate duplicates, and then `xargs` is used to `cd` into each directory and run `yourcommandhere`.

You can also write a script to run with xargs.  e.g.

```
find /target -iname '*.xyz' -printf '%h\000' | sort -z -u | 
  xargs -0 -r /path/to/myscript.sh
```

simple myscript.sh example:

```
#!/bin/sh

for d in "$@" ; do
  cd "$d"
  echo "Match found in $d. Going to execute command"
  # execute command
done
```

This second version will be significantly faster if there are many matching directories - it only has to fork a shell once (which then iterates over every argument) rather than forking a shell once per directory.

---

BTW, neither `printf` nor `sort` nor `xargs` are actually needed here....but they do make it a lot easier to read and understand what's happening.  Just as importantly, by eliminating the duplicates early (with the printf and sort), it runs a lot faster than using bash only and eliminates the (fairly minimal) risk of executing the command more than once in any given directory.

Here's another way of doing the same thing, without sort or xargs:

```
find /target -iname '*.xyz' -exec bash -c \
    'typeset -A seen
     for f in "$@"; do
       d="$(dirname "$f")";
       if [[ ! -v $seen[$d] ]]; then
         echo "Match found in $d. Going to execute command"
         # Execute command
         seen["$d"]=1
       fi
     done' {} +
```

This uses an associative array in bash (`$seen[]`) to keep track of which directories have already been seen and processed.  Note that if there are many thousands of matching `*.xml` files (enough to exceed the maximum command-line length, so that the bash script is forked more than once) then your command **may** be run more than once in any given directory.

The script executed by find's `-exec` option can be a standalone script, as with the xargs version above.

BTW, any of the variants here could just as easily execute an awk or perl or whatever script instead of a sh or bash script.

Comment: See also `-execdir` which gets rid of the explicit `cd`.

Comment: yeah, i know about -execdir but it can't be used here because a) we're matching filenames (`*.xyz`), and most significantly b) we only want to execute once in each directory regardless of how many .xyz files are in it, and c) we only want to exec bash once (or as few times as possible), not once per matching file.

Comment: wow, this command works like a charm!